# Oracle define field name in query, use in where

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This seems like a really dumb question, but what would be the correct syntax for defining the cutoffAmt field in the where clause?

```
select acct_id
     , sum(amt_due_per3) as tot_amt_due_per3
     , sum(amt_due_per4) as tot_amt_due_per4
     , abs (sum(amt_due_per3) + sum(amt_due_per4)) as cutoffAmt
from ( select acct_id
            , amt_due_per3
            , amt_due_per4
      from mytable
      where acct_id = '4679721000')
where cutoffAmt > 100.0
group by acct_id
```

If I leave off that last where clause, the query works; but with 'where cutoffAmt > 100.0', I get an ORA-00904 invalid identifer.  I've tried it with quotes around the name ("cutoffAmt") and as above.  I've tried it with where abs(tot_amt_due_per3 + tot_amt_due_per4) > 100, and then it complains about those field names.  I can't use the sum in the where clause.  If I just refer to amt_due_per3 and amt_due_per4 in the where clause, it isn't looking at the grouped totals.  (I've deliberately chosen an account where all of the individual amounts are under 100, but the sum of all is above 100.)

I have a much more complex query, thus the query within a query, but the code above is exactly as I have it, except for the table name, and it won't work with this simple snippet either.

Here's my data, if it matters

```
Acct_id     amt_due_per3   amt_due_per4
4679721000      21.75          21.75
4679721000      16.41          19.38
4679721000      28.09          40.31
```

(I'm searching around the web, but I'm not sure what terms to even use in my search, so no success yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WHERE clause filters rows before aggregation. To filter groups, use HAVING clause:

```
select acct_id
     , sum(amt_due_per3) as tot_amt_due_per3
     , sum(amt_due_per4) as tot_amt_due_per4
     , abs (sum(amt_due_per3) + sum(amt_due_per4)) as cutoffAmt
from ( select acct_id
            , amt_due_per3
            , amt_due_per4
      from mytable
      where acct_id = '4679721000')
group by acct_id
having abs (sum(amt_due_per3) + sum(amt_due_per4)) > 100.0
```

Alternatively, wrap in a subquery:

```
select * from (
    select acct_id
         , sum(amt_due_per3) as tot_amt_due_per3
         , sum(amt_due_per4) as tot_amt_due_per4
         , abs (sum(amt_due_per3) + sum(amt_due_per4)) as cutoffAmt
    from ( select acct_id
                , amt_due_per3
                , amt_due_per4
          from mytable
          where acct_id = '4679721000')
    group by acct_id
)
where cutoffAmt > 100.0
```

Comment: That doesn't explain the error, but your answer works and does make sense.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, you get invalid identifier error when you try to use  aliased column names in `where` or `having` clause, you cannot use aliased column names here

Comment: The reason I love StackOverflow is I can get a clear explanation, something that is often never found when searching official docs.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19097787) was for the same error, and includes a link to the documentation for rs.'s explanation. Just for a bit more background.