# Using Aliased column in a join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, alias

I have an aliased colum:

```
FIRST_VALUE(SUBSTR(ba.CREATED,1,18))
OVER (PARTITION BY bsh.STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID, bal.BUDGET_CYCLE_ID 
ORDER BY ba.CREATED DESC NULLS FIRST) AS UPDATED_DATE
```

I need to use this new field in a `join`, how can I do it? I've tried copying the same syntax but I get an error message stating `window functions are not allowed here` and also tried using the `UPDATED_DATE` alias name but that says the field does not exist.

Can anyone advise please?
Edited 24/10/15:
I've tried the suggestions I've been given but they don't seem to be working. I'm not sure if it's because it's already a complex statement with other joins in so this is the full code as it currently is

```
SELECT /* State Change 2 to 3 */
    bal.BUDGET_CYCLE_ID      AS BUDGET_CYCLE_ID,
    bal.STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID AS COST_CENTRE, 
    FIRST_VALUE(SUBSTR(ba.CREATED,1,15))
           OVER (PARTITION BY bsh.STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID,
                              bal.BUDGET_CYCLE_ID, 
                              bsh.PREVIOUS_STATE || bsh.NEW_STATE
                     ORDER BY ba.CREATED DESC NULLS FIRST)         AS UPDATED_DATE,
    bsh.PREVIOUS_STATE AS PREVIOUS_STATE,
    bsh.NEW_STATE AS NEW_STATE,
    ba.USER_ID AS USER_ID
 FROM BUDGET_ACTIVITY ba
 LEFT JOIN BUDGET_ACTIVITY_LINK bal
   ON ba.BUDGET_ACTIVITY_ID =  bal.BUDGET_ACTIVITY_ID
  AND ba.ACTIVITY_TYPE = 5
 LEFT JOIN BUDGET_STATE_HISTORY bsh
   ON bal.STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID = bsh.STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID
  AND bal.BUDGET_CYCLE_ID = bsh.BUDGET_CYCLE_ID
  AND SUBSTR(ba.CREATED,1,15) = SUBSTR(bsh.CHANGED_TIME,1,15)
WHERE PREVIOUS_STATE || NEW_STATE = 23
  AND bal.budget_cycle_ID = '227565'
  AND bal.structure_element_ID = '418'
```

I need to change the `SUBSTR(ba.created,1,15)` to the `UPDATED_DATE` field derived above. I'm relatively new to SQL and this one is beyond me.

Comment: What does the table look like that you're joining to?

Comment: It's just got some user names and times and. A few other dimensional details that I don't need. I basically want to return from that table the latest date in the query I've posted who the user was.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `LAST_VALUE` instead of `FIRST_VALUE`? Maybe I misunderstood... I'm fairly new to Oracle myself.

Comment: The order by descending value flips that around I think so it becomes the first.

Comment: You got errors because you can only use a column alias in an  order-by clause ([as here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19097787/266304)), and you can't use windowing claues in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to put your aliased column in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    ...
    FIRST_VALUE(SUBSTR(ba.CREATED,1,18))
            OVER (PARTITION BY bsh.STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID, bal.BUDGET_CYCLE_ID 
            ORDER BY ba.CREATED DESC NULLS FIRST) AS UPDATED_DATE 
    FROM 
    ...
    ) T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.UPDATED_DATE = T2.DATE_FIELD;
```

Comment: I did try using a select but think I got the syntax all wrong! I've given up for the day now but will try that in the morning! Thanks.

Comment: I tried that but I'm still having no luck - I've edited the post to show the full code I'm using as it's quite complex.